# Python Process Multiple Files

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

As an example, let's say we have 3 CSV files with millions of lines per file:

```
file_1.csv contains 10 million lines
file_2.csv contains 2.5 million lines
file_3.csv contains 7.1 million lines
```

I understand that I could use Python's [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/multiprocessing.html) and process each file in a separate process using one thread per process.

Another idea would be to process each file in a separate process, like above, but within each process have multiple threads working on chunks of the file. For example:

```
Process 1
  file_1.csv being processed
  thread 1 is processing the first 1 million lines
  thread 2 is processing the second 1 million lines
  etc…
  combine thread results
```

… and so on for process 2 and 3.

So, my question is, what is the fastest way to process these files?

Comment: It depends on what kind of processing you are doing and other details. It is difficult to say which one is faster for sure without running the code and measuring time.

Comment: Exactly what @user2040251 said: *it depends*. We need more context, for example: what's your current boundary now, cpu or IO? Profile the execution to determine what the slowest parts are and only then make those your optimization targets.

Answer (score 4):

Using threads to process parts of the file will not improve performance at all (assuming you're using CPython), because of the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Only one thread can run Python bytecode at a time, so anytime your threads need do something other than blocking I/O, only one thread can actually run concurrently. So you end up essentially processing the file sequentially, only with additional overhead caused by switching between the threads.

So, of the two options you came up with, the former will perform better. However, you could potentially improve performance further if you have more than 3 CPU cores on your system, by splitting the files so that every available core on your system is processing a chunk of a file in its own process (and therefore avoiding the GIL). The best way to do that is dependent on what kind of processing you're doing to each csv file. Are you putting data from the csv into a data structure in memory? Doing some kind of calculation on each line?, etc.